# CasperJS test does not run

Tags: casperjs

I have got a problem with my test in CasperJS.

This is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize:{
        width:1920,
        height: 1080
    }
});

casper.start('http://myweb.es/', function() {


})

//COMPROBACION DE POPUP LOGIN
casper.then(function(){
    this.click('.btn-attendee');

    this.waitForSelector(
        '#form_signup2',
        function(){
            //El parametro 'INFO' es para que el echo aparezca en color VERDE
            this.echo('Existe el popup SIGNUP', 'INFO');



            this.capture('signup.jpg', undefined, {
                        format: 'jpg',
                        quality: 75,
                    });
            this.echo('pantallazo signup', 'INFO');

            this.wait(4000, function() {
                this.fill('form#form_signup2', {
                    'first_name':    'Perico',
                    'last_name':    'Palotes',
                    'email':    new Date().getTime()+'@testing.es',
                    'password':    '123456'
                    //Ponemos false porque sino nos haria el SUBMIT del formulario y no queremos eso.
                    //En el email la pasamos un numero aleatorio para que no de fallo al ejecutar el script varias veces
                }, true);



                            //PROBLEM HERE! No run this CLICK
                        this.click('.checkbox');    

                                this.capture('form.jpg', undefined, {
                                            format: 'jpg',
                                            quality: 75,
                                        });

                                        this.echo('pantallazo  form', 'INFO');

            });
        },
        function(){
            //El parametro 'ERROR' es para que el echo aparezca en color ROJO
            this.echo('error login', 'ERROR')
        },
        10000
    );
});

casper.run();
```

My problem is that in the comment `//PROBLEM this.capture` runs but the `this.click` does not run and this class is good and works in the console of firebug with Mozilla.

`this.click` does not run in this part of code.

What's my problem?

Answer (score 1):

you need to learn how casperjs uses jquery.  it has to be passed to the evaluate function inside of your casper function.

If you don't wish to click by jquery, you could just say casper.click(x('yourXpath'));

Otherwise you need to make sure your jQuery attempts to click are using the right context.

high level example to use jquery...

```
casper.then(function () {
// this is your casper function 
    this.evaluate(function () {
        // this is the function that can now manipulate the page using jQuery
        $('.yourClass').click();
    });
});
```